# react-slick custom paging paging prop usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I have set up the prop to pass to react-slick Slider as follows:

```
const settings = {
    customPaging: function(i) {
        return <a><div>{`Test ${i}`}</div></a>
    }
};
```

And pass it into the slider as:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
    {this.Slides()}
</Slider>
```

yet when I test the component I do not get the custom paging that I expected - where I would expect to see the text 'Test 0' I still see the default dot.  I took a look at the custom paging example in the documentation and nothing stood out to me as being different than what I did.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "not working"? The JSX you provided looks wrong as you tried to string interploate without braces. It should've been `<a><div>{\`Test ${i}\`}</div></a>` or straight up `<a><div>Test {i}</div></a>`

Comment: Updated for correct string interpolation - by not work I mean that providing the callback function appears to be ignored.  I would expect to see the text 'Test 0' for the first slide instead of a dot, yet I am still getting a dot.

Comment: Try posting more code, this doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue / solution:

I was on react-slick@0.14.2 which did not include the update for custom paging - upgrading to the latest version of react-slick has fixed the issue