# custom paging slider missing config file for react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, custompaging

I am creating the custom paging slider from https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-paging/ I copied the code directly from the website and follow the instructions and installed the packages. When i try to run the code though i get the following error:

./src/Carousel.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './config.js' in '/Users/mcoe/Documents/Code/my-app1/src'

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import { baseUrl } from "./config.js";

export default class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      customPaging: function(i) {
        return (
          <a>
            <img src={`${baseUrl}"Random1${i + 1}.png`} />
          </a>
        );
      },
      dots: true,
      dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Custom Paging</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "Random1.png"} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "Random1.png"} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "Random1.png"} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={baseUrl + "Random1.png"} />
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the component just wants a base url from a config file. The `baseUrl` needs to be the url path of your images. A relative path should work so if they are stored in `my-app1/public/images/` you should be able to create a file `config.js` in the `src` directory like this:

```
//config.js
export const baseUrl = 'images/';
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed the error. Now I having trouble getting my images to show. im not sure about the syntax for the first <img> tag right after the return statement

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I didn't see where `baseUrl` was being used. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: that connected the images but its not following the slider settings or anything the only time i can see the pictures is by pressing the previous button but its shows them all at once not one at a time. i was doing some searching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150266/react-slick-custom-paging-paging-prop-usage and it said something about updating to the latest version when i do npm install react-slick i get the following:

Comment: npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-slick-carousel@0.14.9 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-slick-carousel@0.14.9 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN slick-carousel@1.8.1 requires a peer of jquery@>=1.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-slick@0.23.1

Comment: Are you loading the CSS, as shown in the quick start guide: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/get-started

Comment: I added the Link tags into the index.html now i am able to switch between them though the dots do not show the thumbail images. Where do the import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import  "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css"; go?

Comment: You don't have to add both the `<link ../>` tags and the import tags. But the import tags go at the top of Carousel.js with the rest of the imports.

Comment: was able to get everything working except the getting the images to appear as the dots and arrows to appear. Ive added the css and added all dependencies. any suggestions?

Comment: That has to be an issue with `settings.customPaging`. You'll have to figure that one out.

Comment: This helps me lot.. :) I just added it on top of the page..!

Answer (score 0):

[What it looks like currently, works. have not gotten the arrows to appear or images to appear in the dots underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWY3I.png)